# In Bash, how can I lazy eval 'date'?

Tags: bash

I have a script that outputs with timestamps but I can't manage to have the date evaluate when the specific line is reached; all of the stamps have the time of the script's first call, that is, they're all the same, even though the script takes hours to complete.

I'm trying this:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date +"%H:%M:%S --"`
...

eval "echo $TIMESTAMP Starting backup"
...
eval "echo $TIMESTAMP Doing something here"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated the example to show that the timestamp is just part of a string, which is why I don't use a function for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases are handy, easy expansion in an echo line. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias now='date +%T'
echo $(now)
sleep 10
echo `now`
sleep 1
echo $(now) My Log line
```

Yielding:

```
15:13:56
15:14:06
15:14:07 My Log line
```

Comment: This is the only answer that allows me to easily append text after the timestamp, e.g.
`echo $(TIMESTAMP) Starting...`
yields:
`19:20:08 -- Starting...`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the backticks evaluate the command inside when you assign to `DATE_COMMAND`.  You could do the following instead:

```
DATE_COMMAND='date +"%H:%M:%S --"'
...
...
eval $DATE_COMMAND
...
...
eval $DATE_COMMAND
```

To be honest, though, I would [avoid `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and just make this a function:

```
timestamp() {
    date +"%H:%M:%S --"
}
...
...
timestamp
...
...
timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write a function to do this?

```
$ function printdate {
>     echo `date +"%H:%M:%S --"`
> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the `TIMESTAMP` variable before each `eval` executes to the current date / time, otherwise the original timestamp value will just be redisplayed. For example:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date +"%H:%M:%S --"`
eval "echo $TIMESTAMP"
...
TIMESTAMP=`date +"%H:%M:%S --"`
eval "echo $TIMESTAMP"
```